# Pasar parametros o Valores desde C# a Crystal Reports en VS2017

Tags: crystal-reports

amigos,estoy trabajando con VS2017 y Crystal Reports,trate de utilizar formulas como parametros a como se hacia en VB6 y CR8.5, pero no me funciono, ahora utilice parametros, estos valores los paso ya, pero me presenta la pantalla de ingresar valores a estos y eso no lo necesito, como puedo hacer para que no la presente, este es el codigo que tengo.

```
frmVisorReports form = new frmVisorReports();
oRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\CReportUsuarios.rpt");
oRpt.SetParameterValue("FechaInicial", "Desde 01-01-2020");
oRpt.SetDataSource(dsReportCatalogos);
form.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;
form.Show();
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda, a como menciono no quiero que se presente la pantalla de ingresar valores a los parametros antes del imprimir.

Saludos

Comment: Hola has probado  a cambiar el orden de setparametervalue y setdatasource y primero hacer poner el setdatasource y luego el setparametervalue?

Comment: Gracias Juanjo por tu recomendacion ya encontre mi Error, en el visor de CR, debo poner en falso el presentar el ingreso o pantalla de parametros manuales. Y segui tu recomendacion, lo ordene a como me indicaste aproveche tambien en ordenar el codigo.